# Async & await function on Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new of Javascript. I am trying to practice to get data from an api. It works if I add async and await in the function. However, if I take out the async and await from the function to a normal function, it will return "TypeError: Cannot read property 'results'.

May I know why it must add an Async and await on this function?

Here is the code:-

```
showMovieData()

async function showMovieData() {
  const api_key = '8c9718c0155061bbd9ae76ee62386c65';
  // /discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc

  var result = await axios.get(
    "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=8c9718c0155061bbd9ae76ee62386c65&sort_by=popularity.desc"
  )

  result = result.data.results;
  console.log(result)
```

Comment: Read about HTTP calls and Promises in JS.

Comment: While writing this it will not wait for Ajax call to complete and carry  out   `result = result.data.results ` . Instead of it use.  `result = await result.data.results`

Comment: `.get` returns a promise object. If you don't `await`, then `result` will be that promise object, which obviously does not have a `data` property.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost: Don't share secret keys on a public forum.

Secondly, the reason you must await it, is because your function is asynchronous. If you do not await the get request, your code will continue to the next line regardless if it has gotten a response from the API or not, meaning if it has **not** received a response, then there is no "data" property to speak of. This is a property the responding API sets for you as it sends back its results. It's not as much Javascript related as it is modern programming.

Answer (score 0):

**In addition for Amar's answer, I'd like to add a little bit**

Firstly you need to understand asynchronicity.
Imagine that I talk to my friend and this is the conversation:

> me: Hey, can you send me the number of the girl from the party last night?
> friend: Sure, I will get home and send it to you

And before he sends me the number, I try to call her.

Doesn't make sense right? So the same logic applies here.

The `async` and `await` keywords means that there is somthing that should happen before the next line of code getting executed.

So if you really want to understand the concept of this asynchronicity, you should learn about [higher-order function](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/game-dev-learn-javascript-higher-order-functions-and-iterators/modules/game-dev-learn-javascript-iterators/cheatsheet), [callback functions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_callback.asp), [promises](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DHvZLI7Db8E&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified), and then the [async&await](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_Kr9OSfDeU&t=304s&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified)

I have added different sources, feel free to read all the subject on any source you want, they're all great.